# Primavera V10 Executar SQL

Tags: sql

Estou a tentar migrar um código Primavera da `V9` para a `V10` que basicamente insere registos SQL numa tabela de utilizador oriundos de um software externo.

Na V9 faço isto facilmente usando por exemplo:

```
strSQLAux = "INSERT INTO TDU_LOTESX3 (CDU_LOT, CDU_QTYSTU, ... etc)
BSO.DSO.BDAPL.Execute strSQLAux
```

Na `V10` estou a tentar fazer a migração do código mas dá-me erro, aparentemente a função `Execute` não existe.

Podem-me ajudar a encontrar uma alternativa para inserir registos SQL na V10 via editor (PEX)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boa tarde, tem de referenciar a ERPDS100.DDL e depois fazer:

```
BSO.DSO.ExecuteSQL(strSQLAux)
```

Comment: Obrigado, era isso mesmo!